# Почему перебрасывает на страницу входа если перезагрузить страницу?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[embed.plnkr.co/Mvrte4/preview](http://embed.plnkr.co/Mvrte4/preview)

В данной ссылке показан пример простой авторизации с использованием AngularJS.

Проблема в том, что если авторизоваться, а потом обновить страницу, то меня перебрасывает опять на страницу входа.

Подскажите в чем проблема, как ее решить?

Comment: выкинь из примера все лишнее, и вставь код непосредственно в вопрос

Comment: не могу удалить ничего, потому что это все нужно для нормальной работы

Comment: конечно можешь. Удаляй все, что не требуется для демонстрации проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше было бы оставить ответ в комментарии, но пока репутации не хватает. 
Вы храните данные в session.js, scope которой обновляется при обновлении страницы. Соответственно, данных в сессии о юзере больше нет после обновления страницы, так как она рендерится заново.

Comment: Что можно сделать, чтобы избежать данной проблемы? Если я правильно понял, мне нужно чтобы данные хранились на бекенде?

Comment: Бэкэнд - это хороший вариант, на мой взгляд. Поищите информацию в интернете по авторизации. 
Как один из вариантов, можно добавить информацию о сессии в базу. Можно также использовать localStorage, что позволит хранить данные в браузере без обращения к бэкэнду.